# Process to clean grid data for node edges model

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

Since a few weeks I have been trying to solve a problem I am facing regarding a spatial data set representing a distribution grid.
I got a set of geospatial data representing a energy distribution grid (gas) for visualization purposes. My goal is to generate a node-edges model from this dataset to do some analysis (mass/energy flow).
Let's assume there is the following example data:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

# Some example Lines
Line1 = LineString([(0,0), (0.5, -1), (3, 0.5)])
Line2 = LineString([(0.5, -1), (0.5, -2), (2, -2.5), (3, -0.5)])
Line3 = LineString([(3, 0.5), (2, 1.5), (2, 0.5)])
Line4 = LineString([(2.5, -1.5), (3.5, -2), (4, 0)])
Line5 = LineString([(3, 0.5), (4, 1)])

# Some example Points
node1 = Point(3, 0.5)
node2 = Point(0.5, -1)
node3 = Point(2.5, -1.5)

dictEdges = {
    'geometry': [Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5],
    'names': ['firstE', 'secondE', 'thirdE', 'fourthE', 'fifthE'],
    'level': ['lp', 'lp', 'lp', 'lp', 'lp'] 
}

dictNodes = {
    'geometry': [node1, node2, node3],
    'names': ['firstN', 'secondN', 'thirdN'],
    'type': ['con', 'con', 'con']
}

edgesGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dictEdges, geometry='geometry')
nodesGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dictNodes, geometry='geometry')

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
ax = plt.gca()

edgesGDF.plot('names', legend=True, ax=ax)
nodesGDF.plot('names', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVw1A.png)

The visualized grid are all stored as shapely.geometries inside an GeoDataFrame. My goal is to gain something like the third node. If there is an edge with more than two nodes attached I need an edge point connection the nodes.
My current approach to clean up the data is:

1. get all start and end points of every line in the dataset
2. for each point search lines within a given max distance around the point
3. for all crossing lines without an existing start or endpoint, cut at the closest distance to current point
4. create new node connecting all found lines around the current point if there is no existing node (here I get a new datastruct representing theses nodes and the connections between these lines)

I have got function python-code for 1 and 3-4. On my search for an approach to search lines around an point in python I found nothing. I already thought of an different approach with intersections of 2d-functions by extending every part of the lines to vectorfunctions and search for intersections between those functions and test if the bounding boxes of the lines connect.
Do you guys have an idea of a better approach to my problem?

My alternative approch with 2d-vectorfunctions and test if the bounding boxes of the lines connect seem to be not the fastest way to search for the intersections.
For my current idea I don't find a way to search for lines around a point. Did I missed an already built in function or is there an mathematical way to do this search?

Comment: Shapely objects have a distance method (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.distance), couldn't you use that to calculate the distance between your point and every lines, and then keep the ones for which that distance stays below a threshold ?